# How does the critical angle determine the visibility of an underwater light source?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometric-optics

> A point source is placed at a depth $h$ below the surface of water (refractive index = $\mu$). The medium above the surface of water is air ($\mu=1$). Find the area on the surface of water through which light comes in air from water.

I solved the question and found the answer. I assumed one thing: the incident angle is the critical angle, but I am not able to justify it.

Please help me to find the justification for this, thank you.

Comment: Consider how the critical angle determines the region where light from the point source can't escape from the water.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/123208

Comment: To the potential close-voters: this is clearly a *conceptual* question. The OP is *not* asking us to check or verify a calculation. They guessed that the critical angle is somehow relevant to the calculation, but they want help understanding *why* the critical angle gives the correct answer.

Comment: You need to [edit] this question to include your thoughts that led you to think that the incident angle is the critical angle. If it was just a random unmotivated guess, then we probably can't help you.